# Unable to deploy django app locally

Tags: python, django, heroku

**Update:** I seem to have some progress, although haven't yet solved the main problem. Currently, I can access tasks as described [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/celery-heroku#running-locally) and this will then produce some output in my local server (specifically, it complains about pickled content, but that feels like another problem for later).

I then tried `telnet localhost 5000` and this successfully connected to localhost. Although after a few seconds, I got a `Connection closed by foreign host.` Not entirely sure what this means, although it is perhaps vaguely encouraging - but I still can't get access via the browser.

---

I have a django app that I'm currently deploying on Heroku, and everything is working fine  there.

However, I'm working  on adding some new stuff for which I've incorporated various additional pieces into the app (redis, Celery). Before deploying this on Heroku, I want to deploy it locally and test it. I'm attempting to do this by using `heroku local` as outlined [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local). I'm doing this from a mac running el capitan - however, when I then attempt to access localhost:5000, I get an error that the page can't be reached because the request timed out.

**Some Relevant Code and Output:**

When running `heroku local`, I get the following in terminal:

```
(venv) computer:dynamicapp $ heroku local
[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format
2:17:52 PM web.1    |  [2016-06-23 14:17:52 +0530] [6188] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.4.1
2:17:52 PM web.1    |  [2016-06-23 14:17:52 +0530] [6188] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (6188)
2:17:52 PM web.1    |  [2016-06-23 14:17:52 +0530] [6188] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2:17:52 PM web.1    |  [2016-06-23 14:17:52 +0530] [6194] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 6194
2:18:04 PM worker.1 |  [path-to-directory]/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/fixups/django.py:265: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in production environments!
2:18:04 PM worker.1 |    warnings.warn('Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never '
2:18:04 PM worker.1 |  [2016-06-23 08:48:04,110: WARNING/MainProcess] [path-to-directory]/dynamicapp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/fixups/django.py:265: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in production environments!
2:18:04 PM worker.1 |    warnings.warn('Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never '
2:18:04 PM worker.1 |  [2016-06-23 08:48:04,111: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@computer.local ready.
```

**My Procfile:**

```
web: gunicorn dynamicapp.wsgi --log-file -
worker: celery worker --app=dynamicapp.celery.app
```

If helpful, I can paste in my various python modules (celery, **init**.py, etc), however it seems like the web and worker are getting started? But for some reason I'm unable to access the app at port 5000.

Edit with additional info:

I've tried connecting from both Chrome and Safari, and Safari is telling me that it can't connect to the server "0.0.0.0". Potentially relatedly, it seems that both Chrome and Safari are forcing this to connect over https - could that be breaking it?

Answer (score 0):

[0.0.0.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0) is a special address. In this context, it means *"all IPv4 addresses on the local machine"*, i.e.: the server will accept connections to port `5000` on any IP address your machine has.

Thus you can connect to it using `http://127.0.0.1:5000` or using `http://<the ip you got from your router>:5000`

Comment: unfortunately, none of those seem to work either - I just tried connecting via both of those, and am getting a `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error.

Comment: Updated the main post with some more information, any thoughts would be much appreciated